# Fortran MPI slowdown of highly parallel task

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I have been trying to diagnose why my Fortran code will not scale well and have reduced the program down to a very simple test case which still will not scale well. The test case is below. I am trying to create an array, split it evenly between processors, and then do some operation on it (in this case just scale it by `weights`).

I am not passing any information between processes so it seems to me that this should scale well, however, as I run with increasing number of processors and normalize by the number of elements in the array that each processor operates on I see that there is very poor scaling:

2 Processors:

```
For Rank: 0 Average time for 100 iterations was 6.3680603710015505E-009 with 25525500 points per loop
For Rank: 1 Average time for 100 iterations was 6.3611264474244413E-009 with 25576551 points per loop
```

3 Processors:

```
For Rank: 2 Average time for 100 iterations was 8.0085945661011481E-009 with 17102085 points per loop
For Rank: 0 Average time for 100 iterations was 8.2051102639337855E-009 with 16999983 points per loop
For Rank: 1 Average time for 100 iterations was 8.2249291072820462E-009 with 16999983 points per loop
```

4 Processors:

```
For Rank: 0 Average time for 100 iterations was 1.0044801473036765E-008 with 12762750 points per loop
For Rank: 3 Average time for 100 iterations was 1.0046922454937459E-008 with 12813801 points per loop
For Rank: 1 Average time for 100 iterations was 1.0178132064014425E-008 with 12762750 points per loop
For Rank: 2 Average time for 100 iterations was 1.0260574719398254E-008 with 12762750 points per loop
```

6 Processors:

```
For Rank: 1 Average time for 100 iterations was 1.5841797042924197E-008 with 8525517 points per loop
For Rank: 4 Average time for 100 iterations was 1.5990067816415119E-008 with 8525517 points per loop
For Rank: 0 Average time for 100 iterations was 1.6105490894647526E-008 with 8474466 points per loop
For Rank: 3 Average time for 100 iterations was 1.6141289610460415E-008 with 8474466 points per loop
For Rank: 5 Average time for 100 iterations was 1.5936059738580745E-008 with 8576568 points per loop
For Rank: 2 Average time for 100 iterations was 1.6052278119907569E-008 with 8525517 points per loop
```

I am running on a MacPro 8 core desktop with 64 GB of RAM so it shouldn't be constrained by system resources and without any actual message passing I don't know why it should progressively run slower as more cores are utilized. Am I missing something obvious that should cause this issue? Using GCC 5.1.0 and Open MPI 1.6.5 (EDIT: using -O3 flag). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Code:

```
PROGRAM MAIN
    use mpi
    implicit none
    real*8,allocatable::MX(:,:,:)
    real*8,allocatable::XFEQ(:,:,:,:)

    integer:: rank, iter, nte
    INTEGER:: top,bottom,xmin,xmax,zmin,zmax,q,ymax,ymin
    integer:: num_procs, error

    call MPI_Init ( error )                                 !  Initialize MPI.
    call MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, error ) !  Get the number of processes.
    call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, error )      !  Get the individual process ID.

    q = 7
    xmin = 0
    ymin = 0
    zmin = 0

    ymax = 1000
    xmax = 1000
    zmax = 50

    nte = 100

    top    =  rank   *ymax/num_procs
    bottom = (rank+1)*ymax/num_procs-1
    if (rank+1 == num_procs) bottom = ymax

    allocate(MX   ((ZMIN):(ZMAX),(xMIN):(xMAX),(top):(bottom)))
    allocate(xfeq  (0:Q-1,(ZMIN):(ZMAX),(xMIN):(xMAX),(top):(bottom)))

    DO ITER = 1, nte
        MX = 1
        CALL COMPFEQ(top, bottom, xmin, xmax, zmin, zmax, q, rank, iter, nte, xfeq, mx)
    ENDDO

!clean up and exit MPI
call MPI_Finalize ( error )

contains
SUBROUTINE COMPFEQ(top, bottom, xmin, xmax, zmin, zmax, q, rank, iter,  nte, xfeq, mx)
    implicit none
    INTEGER::I,J,L,top,bottom,xmin,xmax,zmin,zmax,q,rank, iter,  nte
    real*8::xfeq(0:Q-1,(ZMIN):(ZMAX),(xMIN):(xMAX), (top):(bottom))
    real*8::MX((ZMIN):(ZMAX),(xMIN):(xMAX),(top):(bottom))
    real*8::weight(0:q-1)

    real*8::time_start, time_stop, time_col = 0
    integer :: count
    count = 0

    weight(0) = 0.25
    weight(1:q-1) = 0.125
    CALL CPU_TIME ( TIME_start )
    DO J=top,bottom
    DO I=XMIN,XMAX
    DO L=zmin, zmax
        XFEQ(:,L,I,J) = weight*MX(L,I,J)
        count = count +1
    ENDDO
    ENDDO
    ENDDO
    CALL CPU_TIME ( TIME_stop )

    time_col = time_col + (time_stop - time_start)/count

    if (iter == nte) print*, "For Rank: ",rank, "Average time for ",nte,'iterations was', &
                                time_col/(iter+nte), "with ", count, "points per loop"

END SUBROUTINE

END PROGRAM
```

Comment: at first glance, your program is memory bound, and that can explain why scaling on a single socket is not ideal (since the memory bandwidth is shared between all the MPI tasks).

Comment: It would also be good to use the timing functions provided by MPI